# APEX Migration to Weblogic now throws certificate error

Tags: weblogic, ssl-certificate, oracle-apex

Ever since moving an internal apex website from the embedded PL/SQL gateway to a weblogic server browsers throw certificate errors.

How can i get rid of these errors/fix the certificates?

Internet Explorer:

```
The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by 
a trusted certificate authority. Security certificate problems may 
indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server
```

Chrome:

```
You attempted to reach sy02131.adt.com, but the server presented a 
certificate issued by an entity that is not trusted by your computer's
operating system. This may mean that the server has generated its own 
security credentials, which Google Chrome cannot rely on for identity 
information, or an attacker may be trying to intercept your communications.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, the embedded SQL gateway (EPG) uses no SSL.  It looks like your Weblogic instance did or even requires SSL.  It's probably using a set of starter keys that you're meant to replace.  At any rate, your browser is causing this problem, not the server.  You should be able to bypass this as a warning in the browser or add an exception.  If you want this error to go away in production, get some proper SSL keys from a certificate authority.

Here is how to configure them once you get them:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/secmanage/ssl.html

Comment: thanks for the help. I should probably have taken the question down. After doing some research we disabled SSL for the Server in Weblogic.